# Can I recover my previous Windows 7 operating system from the windows.old file?

Tags: windows-7, windows

About three months back I sent my CPU to a local vendor and service for dual boot istallation of XP alongwith my existing Windows 7. The idiot accidentally formatted the entire system thus losing me all my valuable files and folders created over years of hard work and replacing it with a really degraded XP.

I never made a system image backup because I never expected this would happen.

I had a new installation of Windows 7 and after a few days I had it upgraded to Windows 10

Is there anyway I can recover my previous installation of Windows 7 OS using windows.old

Comment: The only things relevant are the last two sentences. The beginning is an irrelevant story, I don't see how it pertains to you upgrading from 7 to 10 and wanting to go back to 7.

Comment: I Intended Full Disclosure By Telling Everything So That Someone Can Help Me.I First Had A Windows 7 Containing All My Essential Files and Folders Then The Vendor Accidentally Formatted My System Installing XP Which Replaced That Win7.Then I Had Installed A New Win 7 Which Was Upgraded To Win 10 A Few Days LATER    I Told The Story So That Someone Who Can Help Me Has Complete Background I Am Looking For Ways To Recover My Original Win 7.Win.old File Is Just An Idea

Comment: @shah Recovering your **original** Windows 7 installation (the one that was wiped when XP was installed) will be impossible as since then 1/ The disk was formatted 2/ Windows XP was installed 3/ a new Windows 7 was installed 4/ Windows 10 was installed and your new WIndows 7 moved to windows.old. Any data on disk from your **original** Windows 7 will been overwritten many times. It is extremely unlikely you can recover anything.

Comment: There may still be file signatures on the disk for bare recovery.

Comment: @shah just to note that capital letters should come at the start of a sentence. Having capital letters before every word makes things really hard to read.

Comment: @ DavidPostill So Do you have any good data recovery software that might help i found a few on the web claiming they can recover overwritten data just for the record a new win 10 was not installed but the win 7 was upgraded,does that overwrite evrything????

Comment: [See this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971760)

Comment: @shah. Please read my previous comment. Recovering your original Windows 7 installation (the one that was wiped when XP was installed) will be impossible as since then 1/ The disk was formatted 2/ Windows XP was installed 3/ a new Windows 7 was installed 4/ Windows 10 was installed and your new WIndows 7 moved to windows.old. Any data on disk from your original Windows 7 will been overwritten many times. It is extremely unlikely you can recover anything.

Answer (score 1):

`@insane:` **Your method only rerolls the computer back to his NEW Windows 7 installation**. It does not recover the OLD Windows 7 (with all the files). The Windows.old folder is only created by the Windows installer (Media Creation Tool) when upgrading. Since Windows XP wasn't installed from the CD/ISO/Installer, and that the system was reformatted, there is no Windows.old folder containing your OLD Windows 7 (with all the files). **The Windows.old on your computer NOW contains only your NEW installation of Windows 7 (after the mess-up).**

I'm sorry, but if you don't have a backup of your old system I don't think your old files can be recovered. A Google search might find some answers though.

Comment: So Any Other Idea You Got??? Any Data Recovery Software??? Trust Me I Am Desparate To Try Anything(BTW Can The Windows.old File  of Previous Windows 7 File Be Recovered and Then Used To Get The Original One?? )

Comment: Piriform's file recovery might work. So may @active partition recovery. I apologize for the mishap. I understand what it feels like. (It has happened to me by myself)

Comment: After I Had The New Win 7 I Did A Scan Using EaseUS I Recall Windows.old File Dated The Day Of Formatting.Do You Think Recovering That File Would Help Me????

Answer (score 1):

Data recovery isn't magic. One does not simply expect data to be recoverable.

Lets talk theory. On a modern drive, a single overwrite will result in the data that was in a 'sector' to be irrecoverable.

In most cases recovery is possible because the data is still there, the drive just marks it as being 'empty'.

I often use the analogy of the library when talking about data recovery.

Your hard drive is like a library. You have books (sectors) with writing in them (data). You also have an index telling you where a book is. This library has a lazy librarian. When you do a 'quick' format or a recoverable delete, the cluster is marked as being empty. The data is still there, but our librarian sees no point in throwing out a book from a location till its filled.

When that cluster is used, the old data is cleared, and the librarian feeds the old book into the furnace so its warm.

Now, this librarian is not really lazy cause you have *thousands* of books getting shelved, or set on fire (its a warm library). Sometimes they even get moved around and oh, its a heck of a lot of work, and you might wear out your library.

In a *best* case scenario, you might have been able to *immediately* recover the old partition if you had done a quick delete (and torn up the index card). A reinstall would have messed things up a little but I've done a recovery of a OS drive *immediately* after I accidentally formatted it

Over a few months, most of the clusters that your old windows install was on would probably have been used. If you'd set the old drive aside immediately, and attempted a recovery (professional or otherwise), you might have been able to restore your data. Your data is now a metaphorical pile of ash, and there's no way to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to 7 as long as the windows.old hasn't been corrupted somehow and if it's not been 30 days.

---

1. Go to **Settings**, **Update & Security**, then **Recovery**

[image]

2. Select "**Go back to Windows 7**"

[image]

Comment: It's Been Three Months I Have Been Searching The Entire Web For The Best Data Recovery AVAILABLE.Please Read My Entire Story

Comment: You said it's only been a few days since you upgraded to 10 so it shouldn't pertain to you

Comment: A more General Question Is It Possible To Recover Previous Win 7 Installation If You Have The.old Folder.How About If Create Separate Partition And Recover My Prev. Win 7 Installation There

Comment: This answer is off topic

Comment: I'd be more inclined to say the _question_ is confusing, but to each their own.